# Go: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: go

When running my Go program, it panics and returns the following:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x38 pc=0x26df]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.getBody(0x1cdcd4, 0xf800000004, 0x1f2b44, 0x23, 0xf84005c800, ...)
        /Users/matt/Dropbox/code/go/scripts/cron/fido.go:65 +0x2bb
main.getToken(0xf84005c7e0, 0x10)
        /Users/matt/Dropbox/code/go/scripts/cron/fido.go:140 +0x156
main.main()
        /Users/matt/Dropbox/code/go/scripts/cron/fido.go:178 +0x61

goroutine 2 [syscall]:
created by runtime.main
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.0.3/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:221

goroutine 3 [syscall]:
syscall.Syscall6()
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.0.3/src/pkg/syscall/asm_darwin_amd64.s:38 +0x5
syscall.kevent(0x6, 0x0, 0x0, 0xf840085188, 0xa, ...)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.0.3/src/pkg/syscall/zsyscall_darwin_amd64.go:199 +0x88
syscall.Kevent(0xf800000006, 0x0, 0x0, 0xf840085188, 0xa0000000a, ...)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.0.3/src/pkg/syscall/syscall_bsd.go:546 +0xa4
net.(*pollster).WaitFD(0xf840085180, 0xf840059040, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.0.3/src/pkg/net/fd_darwin.go:96 +0x185
net.(*pollServer).Run(0xf840059040, 0x0)
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.0.3/src/pkg/net/fd.go:236 +0xe4
created by net.newPollServer
        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.0.3/src/pkg/net/newpollserver.go:35 +0x382
```

I've looked at the responses others have had to the same exception, but can't see anything simple (i.e. an unhandled error).

I am running it on a machine that does not have access to the API servers listed in the code, but I was hoping it'd return an appropriate error (as I've attempted to catch errors of that kind).

```
package main

/*
Fido fetches the list of public images from the Glance server, captures the IDs of images with 'status': 'active' and then queues the images for pre-fetching with the Glance CLI utility `glance-cache-manage`. Once the images are added to the queue, `glance-cache-prefetcher` is called to actively fetch the queued images into the local compute nodes' image cache.

See http://docs.openstack.org/developer/glance/cache.html for further details on the Glance image cache.
*/

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    /*
        "log"
        "log/syslog"
    */
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func prefetchImages() error {

    cmd := exec.Command("glance-cache-prefetcher")
    err := cmd.Run()

    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("glance-cache-prefetcher failed to execute properly: %v", err)
    }

    return nil
}

func queueImages(hostname string, imageList []string) error {

    for _, image := range imageList {
        cmd := exec.Command("glance-cache-manage", "--host=", hostname, "queue-image", image)
        err := cmd.Run()

        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("glance-cache-manage failed to execute properly: %v", err)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Image %s queued", image)
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func getBody(method string, url string, headers map[string]string, body []byte) ([]byte, error) {

    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, bytes.NewReader(body))

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    for key, value := range headers {
        req.Header.Add(key, value)
    }

    res, err := client.Do(req)
    defer res.Body.Close()

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var bodyBytes []byte

    if res.StatusCode == 200 {
        bodyBytes, err = ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    } else if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    } else {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("The remote end did not return a HTTP 200 (OK) response.")
    }

    return bodyBytes, nil

}

func getImages(authToken string) ([]string, error) {

    type GlanceDetailResponse struct {
        Images []struct {
            Name   string `json:"name"`
            Status string `json:"status"`
            ID     string `json:"id"`
        }
    }

    method := "GET"
    url := "http://192.168.1.2:9292/v1.1/images/detail"
    headers := map[string]string{"X-Auth-Token": authToken}

    bodyBytes, err := getBody(method, url, headers, nil)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unable to retrieve the response body from the Glance API server: %v", err)
    }

    var glance GlanceDetailResponse
    err = json.Unmarshal(bodyBytes, &glance)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unable to parse the JSON response:", err)
    }

    imageList := make([]string, 10)

    for _, image := range glance.Images {
        if image.Status == "active" {
            imageList = append(imageList, image.ID)
        }
    }

    return imageList, nil

}

func getToken() (string, error) {

    type TokenResponse struct {
        Auth []struct {
            Token struct {
                Expires string `json:"expires"`
                ID      string `json:"id"`
            }
        }
    }

    method := "POST"
    url := "http://192.168.1.2:5000/v2.0/tokens"
    headers := map[string]string{"Content-type": "application/json"}
    creds := []byte(`{"auth":{"passwordCredentials":{"username": "glance", "password":"<password>"}, "tenantId":"<tenantkeygoeshere>"}}`)

    bodyBytes, err := getBody(method, url, headers, creds)

    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    var keystone TokenResponse
    err = json.Unmarshal(bodyBytes, &keystone)

    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    authToken := string((keystone.Auth[0].Token.ID))

    return authToken, nil
}

func main() {

    /*
        slog, err := syslog.New(syslog.LOG_ERR, "[fido]")

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("unable to connect to syslog: %v", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        } else {
            defer slog.Close()
        }
    */

    hostname, err := os.Hostname()

    if err != nil {
        // slog.Err("Hostname not captured")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    authToken, err := getToken()

    if err != nil {
        // slog.Err("The authentication token from the Glance API server was not retrieved")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    imageList, err := getImages(authToken)

    err = queueImages(hostname, imageList)

    if err != nil {
        // slog.Err("Could not queue the images for pre-fetching")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    err = prefetchImages()

    if err != nil {
        // slog.Err("Could not queue the images for pre-fetching")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    return
}
```

Answer (score 202, accepted):

According to the docs for [`func (*Client) Do`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Do):

> *"An error is returned if caused by client policy (such as CheckRedirect), or if there was an HTTP protocol error. A non-2xx response doesn't cause an error.*
>
> *When err is nil, resp always contains a non-nil resp.Body."*

Then looking at this code:

```
res, err := client.Do(req)
defer res.Body.Close()

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

I'm guessing that `err` is not `nil`. You're accessing the `.Close()` method on `res.Body` before you check for the `err`.

The `defer` only defers the function call. The field and method are accessed immediately.

---

So instead, try checking the error immediately.

```
res, err := client.Do(req)

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer res.Body.Close()
```

Comment: Perfect! moving defer after error checking solved it.

Comment: if err != nil , res.Body = nil , why res.Body.Close() can be call?

Comment: @oohcode if err != nil then res.Body.Close() is never called, because there is a return statement inside the if-block.

Answer (score 16):

The nil pointer dereference is in line 65 which is the defer in

```
res, err := client.Do(req)
defer res.Body.Close()

if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

If err!= nil then res==nil and res.Body panics.
Handle err before defering the res.Body.Close().

Answer (score 11):

Since I got here with my problem I will add this answer although it is not exactly relevant to the original question. When you are implementing an interface make sure you do not forget to add the type pointer on your member function declarations. Example:

```golang
type AnimalSounder interface {
    MakeNoise()
}

type Dog struct {
    Name string
    mean bool
    BarkStrength int
}
    
func (dog *Dog) MakeNoise() {
    //implementation
}
```

I forgot the **(dog *Dog)** part, I do not recommend it. Then you get into ugly trouble when calling `MakeNoise` on an `AnimalSounder` interface variable of type `Dog`.

Comment: Was the reason for me. Damn i will have to make sure to comment this on every interface so i  dont forget

Comment: I got the same issue before and didn't know it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I get error when i write unit test in golang.
I write file main_test.go and xxx_test.go. I don't make sure why it raise error when i write:

- **main.go**

```
    
    var testQueries *Queries
    var testDB *sql.DB
    
    func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
        testDB, err := sql.Open(dbDriver, dbSource)
        if err != nil{
            log.Fatal("Cannot connect to db: ", err)
        }
    
        testQueries = New(testDB)
    
        os.Exit(m.Run())
    }
```

and in file xxx_test.go

```
package db

func TestTransferTx(t *testing.T) {

   store = NewStore(testDB)

    account1 := createRandomAccount(t)
    account2 := createRandomAccount(t)
    fmt.Println(">> before:", account1.Balance, account2.Balance)
```

**when i declare `store` in xxx_test.go i get error, but if i declare in main_test.go i fix error :)**

- overwrite main.go

```
var testQueries *Queries
var testDB *sql.DB
var testStore *Store

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    testDB, err := sql.Open(dbDriver, dbSource)
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal("Cannot connect to db: ", err)
    }

    testQueries = New(testDB)
    testStore = NewStore(testDB)

    os.Exit(m.Run())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Very common use case

The error: 
 `Go: panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

Can be caused by multiple reasons that all of them are eventuially related to memory allocations.

I'll add another **very common use case** (but not trivial for beginners) that this error might occur: 
 **Unit testing**.

In case you're writing a unit test for a specific function that is **referring to a variable that was initialized outside the function**. 
When you will try to test this function you will get the panic error.

#### Example

For example, a function named `ValidateTag` has a dependency in a 3rd-party validation library:

```
func ValidateTag(tag string) (bool, error) {
    errs := validator.validate(tag) # <--- Validator Struct should already be initialized
    if errs != nil {
        return false,errs
    }
    return true, nil
}
```

Has we can see, the `validator` struct should be initialized outside the the `ValidateTag` because it is being used in multiple places in the main code.

###### Failing

So if our testing function will not initialize the `validator` struct:

```
import "testing"

func TestValidateAction(t *testing.T){
    ans, _ := ValidateTag("Some-Tag")
    if ans != "Bravo" {
        t.Errorf("Error!")
    }
}
```

We will get the invalid memory address error.

###### Working

Here we're importing the relevant validation library and initializing the variable that was allocated outside the target function:

```
import (
    "testing"
    "github.com/some-validator-library/validator"
)


func TestValidateAction(t *testing.T){
    validate = validator.New() # <-- Here
    ans, _ := ValidateTag("Some-Tag")
    if ans != "Bravo" {
        t.Errorf("Error!")
    }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

I know this might be a coding question, but for others who were looking for another answer, the issue was that I have the program running in powershell and closed powershell without killing the process. The process was using the same port so it was failing with the same error above. I have to manually kill the process and then it worked fine.

Comment: Totally unrelated since this question is about golang and not powershell.

Answer (score -5):

Make sure that you handle all the errors by sending a return value.

```golang
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```