# Not able to access gcp secret manager from standalone go application

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to access GCP secret manager from google cloud function. Below is the code snippet

```
// Package p contains an HTTP Cloud Function.
 package p

 import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    
    

    secretmanager "cloud.google.com/go/secretmanager/apiv1"
        secretmanagerpb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/secretmanager/v1"
)
   
 func main() {
    
    ctx := context.Background()
        client, err := secretmanager.NewClient(ctx)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Errorf("failed to create secretmanager client: %v", err)
        }
        defer client.Close()
        name := "projects/485126440943/secrets/APIAdminServiceAccountLookupKey"
        // Build the request.
        req := &secretmanagerpb.GetSecretRequest{
                Name: name,
        }

        // Call the API.
        result, err := client.GetSecret(ctx, req)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Errorf("failed to get secret: %v", err)
        }

        replication := result.Replication.Replication
        fmt.Printf("Found secret %s with replication policy %s\n", result.Name, replication)
        //return nil

    }
```

But i am getting secretManagerClient as Nil ]. Thats why after running code I am getting below error:

panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

How to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: check this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280176/go-panic-runtime-error-invalid-memory-address-or-nil-pointer-dereference) which might help

Comment: are you getting any error from 'secretmanager.NewClient(ctx)'?

Comment: Why you don't load the secret with Cloud Functions configuration instead reading the secret in your code?

Answer (score 2):

From your codes, we can see that you forgot to stop the program when getting an error. It will lead you to the nil pointer panic because you access the method of nil `*secretmanager.Client` in `client.GetSecret(ctx, req)`. To solve this, you just need to add `panic` or `return` statement. After implementing it, you will no longer get a nil pointer panic and you will face an error from `secretmanager.NewClient(ctx)`.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    secretmanager "cloud.google.com/go/secretmanager/apiv1"
    secretmanagerpb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/secretmanager/v1"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := secretmanager.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        // stop your program from executing the next lines
        panic(fmt.Errorf("failed to create secretmanager client: %v", err))

        // you can also use return statement
        //
        // log.Println(fmt.Errorf("failed to create secretmanager client: %v", err))
        // return
    }
    defer client.Close()

    name := "projects/485126440943/secrets/APIAdminServiceAccountLookupKey"
    // Build the request.
    req := &secretmanagerpb.GetSecretRequest{
        Name: name,
    }

    // Call the API.
    result, err := client.GetSecret(ctx, req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("failed to get secret: %v", err))
    }

    replication := result.Replication.Replication
    fmt.Printf("Found secret %s with replication policy %s\n", result.Name, replication)
    //return nil
}
```

Comment: `panic` will cause the program to end with a non-zero - ie error - exit status.  `return` will not.  So i recommend against `return`ing from main function in error condition.  You don't want programs that return `0` exit status whether or not they worked.

Comment: @DanielFarrell - I do not understand your comment **You don't want programs that return 0 exit status whether or not they worked**. Exit status 0 is a proper exit status.

Comment: @DanielFarrell - Yes, you are right. `panic()` will cause the program to end with a non-zero exit status. From the author's code, we can see that an error from `secretmanager.NewClient(ctx) ` is an unwanted situation. Since the code is running in the main function, we should return a non-zero exit status instead of a zero exit status. But we should do `return err` if the code is being called by another function.

Comment: "you can also use return statement" I mean to say, this is a bad practice to exit the program on failure because it signals success.  0 is only the appropriate exit status if the program didn't fail.  Panic or `os.Exit(1)` are better options for abort due to failure